# How can I add web content type in liferay 6?

Tags: liferay

The default types:

```
1- test
2- General
```

and so on

How can I add web content type in liferay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add any extra types in portal-ext.properties for the following property and restart the server

journal.article.types=announcements,blogs,general,news,press-release,test

Comment: Thank you san.but this file is not exist, will I have to create it?

Comment: Yes, you will have to create it in {tomcat}\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes folder.

Comment: Yes. One of the good things about Liferay is its customizable for most of the changes as the one you wanted. The default property file which has most of the configuration defined is portal.properties. It is well documented. It is packaged in a jar. This link should give you the idea of the default value of various properties http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Properties+6.0.5 Now any property can be overrided by creating a property file named portal-ext.properties and putting your version of properties