# New Content Type Creation In Liferay

Tags: liferay

I am trying to create a new content type in liferay. Just as the existing content types it already has (blogs,discussions or posts) , we would like to have a new content type holder(example : photo) in our application which can have the same features as the existing ones.

Firstly is it possible to customize liferay to achieve this ?
If yes, any pointers to the same will be of great help !!

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add web content type in liferay 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787562/how-can-i-add-web-content-type-in-liferay-6)

Answer (score 1):

Extends the portal-ext.properties:

```
journal.article.types=announcements,blogs,general,news,press-release,test
```